# How to I view a variable when debugging in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, debugging

The Node.js debugger hides most of my string variables, it prints `...` instead, like so: (there's a variable named `source`)

```
$ node debug 127.0.0.1:9101
debug> 
debug> exec('source')
'<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="DW dw-pri js no... (length: 6408)'
debug>
debug> repl
Press Ctrl + C to leave debug repl
> source
'<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="DW dw-pri js no... (length: 6408)'
```

As you can see, it replaces most of the string, with `...`. I've googled for a while and typed `help` in the console. Finally posting here — how do I view the full contents of the string?  `console.log(source)` didn't do anything.

*Edit:* Now I noticed that `console.log` does print the variable, in Selenium's terminal window, which perhaps is what I ought to have expected. Not sure if `console.log` and switching to the Selenium terminal window, is what I'm supposed to do

*Update:*

Typing just `source` doesn't work, outside `repl`:

```
debug> source
ReferenceError: source is not defined
    at repl:1:1
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInContext (vm.js:32:29)
    at Object.runInContext (vm.js:87:6)
    at Interface.controlEval (_debugger.js:971:21)
    at REPLServer.eval (_debugger.js:745:41)
    at bound (domain.js:280:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:536:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:191:7)
```

(and when inside repl, the variable gets truncated, as shown in the topmost snippet above.)

And `print(source)` or `print('source')`:

```
debug> print('source')
ReferenceError: print is not defined
    at repl:1:1
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInContext (vm.js:32:29)
    at Object.runInContext (vm.js:87:6)
    at Interface.controlEval (_debugger.js:971:21)
    at REPLServer.eval (_debugger.js:745:41)
    at bound (domain.js:280:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:536:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:191:7)
debug> repl
Press Ctrl + C to leave debug repl
> print(source)
ReferenceError: print is not defined
```

There aren't many commands to choose among: (in the debugger)

```
debug> help
Commands: run (r), cont (c), next (n), step (s),
out (o), backtrace (bt), setBreakpoint (sb), clearBreakpoint (cb),
watch, unwatch, watchers, repl, exec, restart, kill, list, scripts,
breakOnException, breakpoints, version
```

Comment: Have you tried simply typing the name of your variable without `console.log()` in the debug command line ?

Comment: What about `print` instead of `exec`?

Comment: Hi @Soviut, I tested typing just `source`. Then the debugger won't find `source`, because the `source` variable is available only in the Node.js debuggee process, but not in the debugger itself.

Comment: Hi @OmG, I tested `print` — there's no such function available (not in the debugger, and not inside the repl)

Comment: Is there some reason you are not using devtools?

Comment: @torazaburo I'm using webdriver.io, which forks a child process to run Selenium end-to-end-tests. However, DevTools connects to the main Node.js process ... which is the wrong process.  Command line `node debug 127.0.0.1:9101` connects to the correct process though.   ... Don't know how to tell Chrome to connect to the correct process — the URL seems to contain some magic/secret token: `chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=127.0.0.1:9100/c439ac7f-8022-4b5f-b971-dc50fd73335c` — that's the wrong port: 9100 not 9101. And changing to 9101 doesn't work.

Comment: If you select "Remote Devices", it may show you processes you can connect to, without having to worry about weird URLs.

Comment: @torazaburo When I go to `chrome://inspect/#devices`, 127.0.0.1:9101 won't appear in the "Remote Targets" list, after I added that host:port — however 127.0.0.1:9100 (the main process) does appear, after I added that host:port. Seems to me that somehow only the main process (not the child processes) makes itself reachable from DevTools. ... Also, only the main process logs a `To start debugging, open the following URL in Chrome: chrome-devtools://devtools/....` message.

Answer (score 2):

`watch("your_var_name")` will print the value of the variable(s) you watch at each breakpoint (you must put the variable/expression name in quotes).

This seems to be the closest thing available on the command line, although frankly just writing

`console.log(thing I want to log);
debugger;`

feels easier to me.

Answer (score 0):

@Ryan answers is right, you could easily use `watch('var_name')`;
Furthermore, if you just want to print the value of the *'watched'* variable without step ahead debugging, you can print all the set watchers until now and related values with the keyword `"watchers"`. It will print the list of set watchers and their values.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35387515)